# Quick way to sort an array with respect to row sum in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Here's a small example of what I want. Given the following array:

```
1 1 2
2 2 1
1 1 1
1 1 6
```

Sorted (row sum is shown in parenthesis):

```
1 1 6 (8)
2 2 1 (5)
1 1 2 (4)
1 1 1 (3)
```

Is there a quick way to achieve this in Matlab?

Comment: `sort` returns both a sorted matrix and the order / indexing into the original matrix (i.e. sufficient to recreate the original matrix).  So just sort on the row sums, and use the ordering to select the rows from the original data.

Comment: sort would require a bit more extra work. I found a solution with sortrows (less code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `sort` returns the indexes in order as well as the sorted matrix, you can use these indices to access the original data -- try this:

```
% some data
A = [
  1 1 2;
  2 2 1;
  1 1 1;
  1 1 6;
];

% compute the row totals
row_totals = sum(A,2);

% sort the row totals (descending order)
[sorted, row_ids] = sort(row_totals, 'descend');

% and display the original data in that order (concatenated with the sums)
disp([A(row_ids,:), row_totals(row_ids)])

>>> 
 1     1     6     8
 2     2     1     5
 1     1     2     4
 1     1     1     3
```

Answer (score 4):

The ugliest one-liner I could come up with:

```
>> subsref( sortrows( [sum(A,2) A], -1 ), struct('type','()','subs',{{':',1+(1:size(A,2))}}) )

ans =

 1     1     6
 2     2     1
 1     1     2
 1     1     1
```

Disclaimer: I don't think anyone should write this kind of code, but it's a nice practice to keep your Matlab's skills sharp.

Comment: @Shai Aha, you were taking care of order in `subsref` arguments.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia indeed, but the `-1` argument is much better. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 2):

Just do something very simple like follows

```
temp = [1 1 2
        2 2 1
        1 1 1
        1 1 6];
rowSums = sum(temp,2);
[~,idx] = sort(rowSums,'descend');
output = [temp(idx,:),rowSums(idx)];
```

**EDIT**

Changed the above code to make sure the sum is appended to the last column. I did not notice that this was a requirement when I read the question initially.

Comment: your edit is not in place, there is no such requirement. If it was, a one-liner was extra simple: `sortrows( [temp, sum(temp,2)], -size(temp,2)+1 )`

Comment: oh, well whatever. it is just as easy to remove it as it was to add. So whatever

Answer (score 2):

I leave it for you to judge if this is uglier than @Shai's:

```
fliplr(diff([sortrows(fliplr(-cumsum(A,2))) zeros(size(A,1),1) ],1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some matrix multiplication

```
>> sortrows([sum(A,2) A], -1)*[zeros(1,size(A,2)); eye(size(A,2))]
```

returns

```
ans =
     1     1     6
     2     2     1
     1     1     2
     1     1     1
```