# How to sort a matrix in the ascending order by the sum of its row in Python?

Tags: python

The exact same question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721094/quick-way-to-sort-an-array-with-respect-to-row-sum-in-matlab) but in MATLAB.

My question is this: Given a matrix, sort it in the ascending order according to the sum of its rows.
That is, if `A` is the following matrix:

```
A = [[9, 8, 7],
     [2, 5, 7], 
     [1, 3, 4]]
```

therefore, I would get:

```
B = [[1, 3, 4],
     [2, 5, 7], 
     [9, 8, 7]]
```

because the sum of the 1st row of `A` is `24`, the sum of the 2nd row of `A` is `14`, and the sum of the 3rd row of `A` is `8`. Hence, the 1st row of `B` will be the 3rd row of `A`, the 2nd row of `B` will be the 2nd row of `A`, and the 3rd row of `B` will be the 1st row of `A`.

I am looking for a solution that uses built-in function (if possible). I am not looking for an algorithm for this.

Comment: use the `sort` method of the list object (or the `sorted` free function) and pass `sum` as the `key`. So `sorted(A, key=sum)` should work (or something like it, I haven't tested).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built-in function, [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted), available that does the trick. The command

```
sorted(A, key=sum)
```

gives you the desired output:

```
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 7], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to use the sum of the columns?

Comment: Then you could transpose your matrix first and then apply the same function.

Comment: Thanks. I  missed that, my bad.

Comment: I am recieving this error, can someone add in answer how to resolve this? ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @mattsmith5: probably best to open a new question and link to this one as reference. Right now it is difficult to help as we don't know your input.

Comment: hi @Cleb coworker just posted question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66900594/python-sort-numpy-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-ele

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with NumPy, this would be

```
B = A[np.argsort(A.sum(axis=1))]
```

where the `sum` call computes the sum of each row, `argsort` computes the indices of the smallest, second-smallest, etc. sums, and `A[...]` selects the rows at those indices. This is assuming A is a NumPy array, rather than a list of lists.

To do the same with columns, it would be

```
B = A[:, np.argsort(A.sum(axis=0))]
```